# HP Deskjet 1000 paused after printing one document

Tags: printing

After printing one job the printer stops printing. The printer is "Enabled" in System Settings->Printes. You can see it in the tray bar when you click on the printer, it will say "Paused".  This issue is intermittent, sometimes you can print 5 documents, sometimes only 1.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.10 the solution was to add a new line:

```
ErrorPolicy abort-job
```

to `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and restart cups:

```
sudo service cups restart
```

Another workaround: if the above does not help, just do a `sudo service cups restart` every time the printer is paused.